Voltage threshold using a P-Channel MOSFET
I am kind of newbie with P-Channel MOSFETs. I do have the following schematic:

The MOSFET I am using has the following datasheet:
https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2410010304_Alpha---Omega-Semicon-AO3401A_C15127.pdf
Problem I have is on understanding how does the threshold voltage works. As seen on the datasheet:
Vgs (max) = -1,3V
If I plug the gate pin direct to +3v3 or to +5V (referenced to ground), MOSFET activates (+5V in the INCREMENT label node). If I plug the gate direct to +12V, MOSFET does not activate (0V in the node).
Does it mean that the gate needs to be 1,3V higher than the source for the MOSFET to deactivate? If so, it would be impossible to turn a small voltage (+3v3) to a greater voltage (+5v) with this kind of MOSFET!
Where am I losing here?
Thank you very much!

For a P-channel MOSFET, the gate has to be lower than the source to turn on, while a gate voltage equal or higher to the source voltage turns it off. This is the opposite of an N-channel FET, where the gate has to be higher than the source to turn on.
This means that you can't drive a P-channel FET directly off of low-voltage logic if the source voltage is higher than the logic level. Typically, you would use an additional N-channel FET or npn BJT as a driver, like so:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that I've swapped your MOSFET out for the manufacturer's recommended replacement, as the AO3401 is scheduled to be discontinued. I've also specified a particular N-channel device, as this does need to be a logic-level FET; many MOSFETs won't turn sufficiently on at just 3.3 V on the gate. Your selection is a bit wider if you use 5 V logic (in which case even a 2N7002 would suffice).
Note that the threshold voltage is not a sharp threshold. It's the voltage at which the FET only just barely begins to turn on, typically where it will let through only a handful of microamps. You need to exceed the threshold voltage by a few volts if you want to turn the FET fully on. Check the datasheet for the gate voltages at which Rdson is specified; you'll want to use at least one of those. They normally specify them at common drive voltages, like 3.3 V, 5 V, or 10 V--sometimes at slightly lower voltages to provide some margin. If there's no Rdson rating below the voltage you want to drive the FET at, pick a different FET. It's quite simply not worth the trouble of characterizing whether it will work. (And no, datasheet curves don't count--those are "typical", not guaranteed values!)

The "load" I do want to control is at +5v. Thing is that if I connect the gate voltage direct at +5v, the MOSFET is still active (+5v in the increment node). It turns off if +12v are placed in the gate pin.

@PepitoGrillo Are you sure the part you have is an AO3401 then? Are you sure the source voltage is actually 5 V? Because what you describe doesn't sound right.

100% sure I do have +5V on the pin. Only thing to check is the chip...

As per what I see in the datasheet Vgs max is 12V. What you have seen that is -1.3v max. Is Vgs(th) (th stands for threshold), which is a different parameter.
Vgs max. Is the maximum source to gate voltage you can apply. To turn it off you would usually drive the gate at the source voltage (Vgs=0). Now, to turn it on you would drive the gate at a negative voltage respect to the source. Say your source it’s at 5V, you would drive to any voltage lower than that.
Vgs threshold is the minimum Vgs at which there starts to be a substantial conduction through the MOSFET. As per your datasheet, typically is -0.9V but it can be as high as -1.3V. This means that, usually, by driving your gate 0.9V lower than the source would be enough to turn it on, but some devices my need to get the gate driven as low as 1.3V below the source.
With the logic voltage you have, you will never be able to drive the MOSFET. You would need some additional circuit to be able to drive the gate at 5V for whenever you want to turn it off.

That is what I thought at first moment. But my problem is that, with the following gate voltages, I get the following MOSFET state:
0v -> MOSFET ON (+5V on the INCREMENT node),
+3v3 -> MOSFET ON (+5V on the INCREMENT node),
+5v -> MOSFET ON (+5V on the INCREMENT node),
+12v -> MOSFET OFF (0V on the INCREMENT node),
As far as I understood on your explanation, the gate voltage needs to be no more than -1,3v than the source. Connecting then the gate to +5v wouldn't need to de-activate the MOSFET?

The behavior you explain sounds bizarre to me. What simulator are you using? What do you mean by needs to be? To be turned the gate voltage has to be 0.9V (Vgs(th)) below the source. The max value is not an absolute rating but the maximum value that an intrinsic parameter can have due to construction. As mentioned, usually 0.9V would be enough to start conduction but you may need a bit more. You could drive to 0 so Vgs would -5 which is still higher than the Vgs max. Note that Vgs != Vgs(th). The first one is an electrical variable and the latter is an intrinsic parameter.

Not simulating anything, I am testing with real components. Ignoring Vgs(max), I am only talking about the threshold. The thing is that if I place the gate direct to 5V, the MOSFET is still active. Same with +3v3 (as expected), and turning off at +12v (as expected). Unexpected things happen at Vgs=5v.

@PepitoGrillo have you double checked the connections, the device and the values? It sounds very strange.

The only thing I wasn't really able to check is the device. I ordered a custom PCB with some components soldered, and it doesn't seem to work. I will do some more testing with known devices and tell.


Does it mean that the gate needs to be 1,3V higher than the source for the MOSFET to deactivate?

No, it doesn't....
With the P channel MOSFET source connected to a positive voltage (5 volts in your example) if the gate is also at 5 volts with respect to ground then the gate-source voltage is zero and, the MOSFET is deactivated. As you reduce the gate voltage with respect to ground the gate-source voltage becomes negative i.e. gate is less than source.
At a gate-source of typically -0.9 volts, the MOSFET channel is regarded as very lightly conducting. This somewhat arbitrary point is defined as producing a drain current of -250 μA. Other P channel MOSFETs may define it at -1 mA.
But, as you can see it is only conducting a small magnitude of current and, for all but the lowest-power applications, the MOSFET is not regarded as activated. And, that -0.9 volts is just a typical value. It can be between -0.5 volts and -1.3 volts according to the data sheet: -


If I plug the gate pin direct to +3v3 or to +5V (referenced to
ground), MOSFET activates (+5V in the INCREMENT label node)

Then either your MOSFET is wired incorrectly, it has failed, it is the wrong MOSFET, it's a fake MOSFET or it isn't a MOSFET. It should begin to show strong signs of activating when the gate is +3.3 volts with respect to ground but, it cannot conduct when the gate voltage is at +5 volts with respect to ground.

That is what I finally thought... It is from a custom PCB, soldered by JLCPCB. I will try talking with them, since the label it appears on top of the chip is different from the one I ordered. I will try and tell.

All you need to do for this site is choose the most useful answer and formally accept it.
